# How to sort on a text block?

Tags: sorting, vim

I have a text of 50000 lines

before change

```
bird={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
zero={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
bed={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
air={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
.......
```

that I would like to change into

```
air={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
bed={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
bird={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
zero={
explain line1
explain line2
...
}
```

My solution is divided into four steps:

1.：`g/{/;/}/s/$/@` (@ is not included in the file)

2.`：g/{/;/}/j!`

3.`：sort`

4.`：%S/@/\r/g`

is there a better solution? one step?

Comment: I have used the substitute-join-sort-split method as well for such tasks. I would be interested in a nice solution as a replacement. I usually get the feeling that awk would probably be a better tool here.

Comment: I would prefer using null terminated string instead of "@" so that external `sort(1)` can be used.  `:%s/}\n/&<CTRL-V><CTRL-J>/g | %!sort -z | tr -d '\000'`

Answer (score 2):

Vim has no built-in notion of "treat these blocks as single units" when sorting; also folding won't help. The approach you've outlined (first join all lines of each block into a single long line, then sort, then unjoin) is the canonical workaround.

Of course, if you need this more often, you can define a custom `:command` for it. For an example (that works with folding) see [this](https://gist.github.com/inkarkat/4145501).